# STM32CubeProg vs STLINK Utility

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, flash, debugging, st-link

There are 2 software tools provided by ST to flash their STM32 MCUs namely [STM32CubeProg](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html) and [STLINK Utility](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link004.html)

STM32CubeProg Page says:
STM32CubeProgrammer (STM32CubeProg) is an all-in-one multi-OS software tool for programming STM32 microcontrollers. It provides an easy-to-use and efficient environment for reading, writing and verifying device memory through both the debug interface (JTAG and SWD) and the bootloader interface (UART and USB).

STLINK Page says:
STM32 ST-LINK Utility (STSW-LINK004) is a full-featured software interface for programming STM32 microcontrollers. It provides an easy-to-use and efficient environment for reading, writing and verifying a memory device.

I wonder if both fulfill the same purpose or if they have any specific use-cases also?

Edit: More details and Link included

Comment: Is there a question here?  The ways you can program these devices is well documented in their datasheets and reference manuals.  These are just two of many off the shelf tools, you (well a software developer) can just as easily write your own from scratch.  The uart and other bootloader interfaces are primarily for programming the flash in the device, your application.  The SWD interface is for jtag like debugging and can be used indirectly to program the flash but can also be used for debugging, stop, start, single step, examine, etc.

Comment: Of the many/countless tools out there you need to read and/or experiment with each one to find out what its features are.